# What are the differences between `include` in tsconfig and `entry` field in webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

What are the differences between `include` in `tsconfig.json` and entry field in webpack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `tsconfig.json`'s include is used in order to specify what files tsc should compile when invoking TSC from the command line.
- The entry field specifies what's the entry file (whose imports will be followed) when using webpack as a bundler.

Generally (and a bit inaccurately):
 - TSC is a *compiler* which means it converts TypeScript files to JavaScript.
 - Webpack is a bundler - which means it takes several modules (followed by imports from an entry field) and bundles them into a single JavaScript file.

JavaScript modules have a concept of a "loader" which is like a file transformation that instructs how to load a certain file when it is imported.

It is possible to tell Webpack to use TypeScript as a loader for `.ts` files (through `ts-loader`) at which point it will compile (using TSC and the tsconfig file). This means that it will load the entry and use TSC to compile all the files it is loading (and the files they're loading and so on).

Generally, using an `entry` and webpack is more desirable.

If you do use the `include` part of tsconfig it will be used by `ts-loader` - it will load files specified by that definition and their interfaces will be available to TypeScript. This is sometimes useful for "global" definitions.

Comment: But if I add the app.ts file to include field, then the app.ts will compile twice?

Comment: It will not, in fact in most likelihood you do not need an `include` field in your `tsconfig.json` at all.